# parsing a C structure in C++

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm looking for a way to parse a C structure in order to get the the name and the type of the variables.

For example I have a structure like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
  int anInt ; 
  float aFloat ; 
}
```

I need to get the types int and float and the 2 strings "anInt" and "aFloat".

After I have to use these values in another function:

```
addValue<int>("anInt") ; 
add Value<float>("aFloat") ;
```

Do you know how to do this automatically, I guess, at compilation  ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to parse a text file containing a struct, this could be done in runtime - search for C parsers. If you want to do it in code (convert a definition to another definition dynamically), what you need are reflections and runtime type information, which are "not so good" in C++ (see: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/RTTI).

Comment: Why exactly do you ask? How many structures do you already have? Please **edit your question** to motivate it and give more details

Comment: There's a lot of context missing here, but assuming you control the original struct, I would declare the original struct using a library like boost fusion. This uses macros to provide functionality like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot do that with standard C++11 template code.

You could consider customizing your C++ compiler to get such information. For example, if compiling your code with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you might consider customizing it with your  [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension (MELT is a domain specific language, implemented by a plugin, to customize GCC). You'll need to understand the details of GCC internal representation (so such an extension might take a week or more of your time).

The [Qt](http://qt.io/) MOC [facility](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html) might perhaps be useful or inspirational. It is parsing a limited form of `class` declaration.

Alternatively you might consider generating the C++ `struct` or `class` representation from some other input; e.g. change your build procedure, perhaps your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile), to generate some `.h` header file (and perhaps some `.cc` C++ translation unit) from your higher level representation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my late reply. I use Qt in my development so it may be a good solution. I am looking at the QMetaObject class but it is not really clear for me to know how to proceed. Do you have an example that can help me? I continue to read about Qt MOC... Thks